# NHibernate Conformist mapping many-to-many using set of simple types instead of set of entities

Tags: nhibernate, collections, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm using NHibernate Conformist mappings. I've already creating some complex mappings using `ManyToMany`, `OneToMany`, `Element`, and `Component` relation types for my various collection properties. But I ran into one today that stumped me.

```
public class Permission
{
    public virtual long PermissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    ...
    public virtual Set<string> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    ...
    public virtual Set<string> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Table `Permission` has columns `PermissionId` and `Name`. Then there is table `UserPermission` with columns `UserId` and `PermissionId` and table `GroupPermission` with columns `GroupId` and `PermissionId`.

As you can see, `Permission` is an entity, and there is a many-to-many relationship between users-and-permissions and between groups-and-permissions. However, for purposes of ease of using the `User` and `Group` objects, I don't want `User` and `Group` to have a `Set<Permission>` (easily accomplished using the `ManyToMany` relation type in Conformist). I want to `User` and `Group` to have a set of permission *names*. Normally I'd achieve this with the `Element` relation type, except for the whole many-to-many-using-join-table problem.

How do I map a collection of **simple** types that are **also** many-to-many?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, I would rather have the Permission class have the sets of User and Groups: (note the set, it is not of the System.Collections.Generic as nHibernate understands ISet to be Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<>

```
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

and in the mapping of Permission:

```
    <set name="Users" table="PermissionUser" lazy="true">
    <key column="PermissionId"/>
    <many-to-many class="User" column="UserId" />
    </set>

    <set name="Groups" table="PermissionGroup" lazy="true">
    <key column="PermissionId"/>
    <many-to-many class="Group" column="GroupId" />
    </set>
```

class User and Group will not have any set of Permissions.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and doesn't help me any at all. I need the `User` class to gave a set of permission names so that, given a `User`, I can check whether they have a given permission in code.

Comment: @NickWilliams: you certainly can check for permissions per User, this query does it: var query = session.QueryOver<Permission>().JoinQueryOver<User>(u => u.Users).Where(t => t.UserId == id); IList<Permission> permissions = query.List<Permission>(); so, apparently, you did not understand the mapping well, and thus thanks for the down vote!. That mapping does give you which user has what permission.

Comment: I understand the mapping just fine, it's just a bad design. The problem is there are only ~300 permissions, but there could be 300 MILLION or more users. The performance issues would be staggering with your approach. The vote down is because the answer did not actually answer my question: how to put a set of permission names in the user and group.

Comment: @NickWilliams: my fault. I understand you now. I honestly did not SEE that you had set<string> permissionName in your Group and User classes. I thought it was set<Permission>, and thus was my answer of reversing the mapping. I do not think of any solution at the moment, but I am sure if you had the whole entity of permission (which you said you do not want) in the User and group classes, you would then be able to add IList<string> PermissionNames { get { return Permissions.Select(x => x.PermissionName).ToList<string>(); } }. Do not know if you can have it without referencing Permission in User

Comment: Yea. After several days of nothing working, I took a different approach. I just changed the database tables backing my model so that the join table uses the permission code instead of the permission ID. That way, I could use `Element` instead of `ManyToMany`.